# How do you prove that 2 nontrivial ideals are the only nontrivial ideals in a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

What do you need to look for in 9rder to prove that 2 nontrivial ideals are the only nontrivial ideals in the ring? I can prove that if my ideals are I and J that I+J=R, where R is the ring, but I don't think this is enough in general. I think that the Chinese theorem has something to do with it.

Comment: In $F[x]/(x^3)$ there are exactly two nontrivial ideals: $(x)$, $(x^2)$, and their sum is certainly not the whole ring.

Comment: Maybe you meant something else, but when I see "prove there are only two nontrivial ideals" I think the strategy is simply to name those two ideals and show that any ideal of the ring is either one of those two ideals, or else $\{0\}$ or $R$.  That would seem to be the most obvious way to start.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by „trivial“. If you mean non-zero, then $R$ is a ring with exactly three ideals. Thus $R$ is a local ring and the ideals are $(0) \subset \mathfrak{m} \subset R$, where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R$. To prove that a ring is local you can show that every element not being in the maximal ideal is a unit.

Since you were saying something about coprime ideals I believe you rather want to show that $R$ has exactly $4$ ideals. What is the ring you are considering?

Comment: By nontrivial I mean {e} and the whole ring R, (a b 0 a) 2x2 matrix where a,b are in Z7. I=(0 b 0 0) J=(a 0 0 a) a,b are in Z7 and 0 is the set of numbers devisible by 7